# Need help with calculus? (converge or diverge)

Tags: calculus

State whether the following series converge or diverge and justify your answer using one of the know tests for convergence or divergence. Please state the name of the test you are using. For alternating series please determine if the series converges conditionally or absolutely.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sqrt 2)^n$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1.001}}$$

Answer (score 2):

For $$\sum(\sqrt 2^n)$$

Is $\sqrt 2<1$?

For $$\sum\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}$$

with $\epsilon >0$, use the integral test, that is, study the integral $$\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{1+\epsilon}}$$ for $\epsilon>0$.